# Connection with oracle in java application

Tags: java, oracle, connection

I have downloaded oracle express 11g edition and installed that.Now i want to connect it  from java application. Here is my  Connection code :-

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver").newInstance();
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:example", "example","password123");
```

But when i am trying to connect it, it showing me following exception.

```
java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:  
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:419)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:536)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:228)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
at javaapplication3.JavaApplication3.main(JavaApplication3.java:40)
```

But when i am trying to connect with "xe" database then it is connected.

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver").newInstance();   
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe", "example","password123");
```

I dont know why this is happening?. Please give me some reference or hint.

Comment: *Listener refused the connection with the following error:*        where is the error?

Comment: yea Abu.. its giving when i am trying to access "example" schema...the first code

Comment: [Refer Here](http://kodehelp.com/how-to-make-jdbc-connection-to-oracle-11g-release-2/)

Comment: @user591790 I mean you have not put the error in the question.Please  edit your question with the error so that people here can help you better.

Comment: have you created `example` database ?

Comment: @Abu: i have created example database

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think, you are misunderstanding between `database schema` and database type. In `Oracle`, `XE` means `Express Edition` of oracle database. `ORCL` means `Oracle Corp`.

In mysql

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "example","password123");

`test` is a database schema.
```

In Oracle XE

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe", "example","password123");
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:scott/tiger@myhost:1521:orcl","example", "password123");

`example`: database schema name and DB user name are the same.
```

Answer (score 5):

The connection URLs for Oracle are in the format:

jdbc:oracle:thin:@HOST:PORT:SID

The SID is a site identifier. In a full oracle install you could have multiple SIDs, but for Oracle Express this will always be `XE`.

What you are refering to as a "database" equates to a "user" in Oracle ("example" in your code above). Tables etc... are created under that user.

Answer (score 1):

In URL pattern XE and orcl are the service  id's for the Oracle.
For Oracle expressed edition "xe" is used and for Oracle Enterprised edition 
"orcl" is used..

Answer (score 0):

Check which instances are known to listener by executing : **lsnrctl services**

Check your tnsnames.ora

Check your SID parameters for typo and invalid parameters value